# What does "this" keyword mean in the code?

Tags: java, multithreading, this

Here is my following code:

```
public class SharedState {

    private static final List<SharedState> list = new ArrayList<>();

    public SharedState() {
        list.add(this); // What does "this" mean here?
        System.out.println(list);
    }


    public static void main(String[] args) {

        Thread t1 = new Thread("t1") {
            @Override
            public void run() {
               /* try {
                    Thread.sleep(200);
                } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                } */
                new SharedState();
            }
        };
        Thread t2 = new Thread("t2") {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                new SharedState();
            }
        };

        t1.start();
        t2.start();
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return "SharedSate";
    }
}
```

- My understanding is `this` refers to the current object and here `list.add(this)` is adding `SharedSate`to the list, right? So that means it's invoking `toString()`, and then It is printing out `list` on the console. Am I right?
- I just wanted to know how this two lines are working:

  `list.add(this);`

  `System.out.println(list);`

Comment: @KevinEsche So what Am I saying that `list.add(this)` is somehow invoking `toString()` is right? Cause that's the only way it can add the elements in the list.

Comment: @KevinEsche It will print whatever is defined in `.toString();`

Comment: IT work in ocnjonction with `private static final List<SharedState> list = new ArrayList<>();` it's a way to have some all application shared values into a singleton.

Comment: `So what Am I saying that list.add(this) is somehow invoking toString() is right? Cause that's the only way it can add the elements in the list.` NO .. That's wrong.

Comment: @JoshuaBakker Yes, but It will add the elements to the list by invoking 'toString()` in the line `list.add(this)`, right?

Comment: It will just add an instance of this class to the list. `toString()` only gets called when you  want to print it.

Comment: @Azodious Then how It is adding elements to the list without calling `toString` while adding elements to the list (list.add(this))?

Comment: @JoshuaBakker yeah you´re right, somehow didn´t notice the `toString` there..

Comment: @KevinEsche In other words it will always print SharedSate.

Comment: Your `list` wants an object of the type `SharedState`, `this` is an object of that type and hence the entire object is saved to the list, not invoking `toString()`.

Comment: @Aidin That means It just have added an entire object to the list, but It actually store `SharedSate` when It print it out?

Comment: Yes, it added the entire object to the list. Not quite sure what you mean by it actually store `SharedState`.... If your list would have been `List<String>` instead you would have added the objects by doing `list.add(this.toString())`

Comment: @Aidin That being said, It has added the entire object to the list and then it jus print it out by invoking `toString()`?

Comment: When you do `System.out.println(list)` it prints out the information about the `list`, not the information about `this`. On the other hand, I believe that writing `System.out.println(this)` is the same as doing `System.out.println(this.toString())` (but don't quote me on this)

Comment: @Hemlata that´s what `List.toString` does.. it iterates itself and prints `instance.toString` on each instance.

Comment: @KevinEsche Can you please elaborate `it iterates itself and prints instance.toString on each instance.` this line again? I kind of got It now how It works, but It will be appreciated If you can elaborate it more.

Comment: @Hemlata check [the code for example](http://grepcode.com/file/repository.grepcode.com/java/root/jdk/openjdk/6-b14/java/util/AbstractCollection.java#AbstractCollection.toString%28%29). by donig `System.out.println(list)` you are practicly invoking the `list.toString` method, because that´s what `System.out.println(Object)` does. the `toString` implementation of `AbstractCollection`, which `ArrayList` inherits from, does simply iterate over it´s own list content and invokes `toString` on each of the `Object`'s that is stored there.

Comment: @KevinEsche That means It will first add the entire object to It (Let's say we've two Objects) and, now It will iterate over them when printing out?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> here list.add(this) is adding SharedSateto the list, right? So that means it's invoking toString()

2nd part of your statement is wrong. Where from did you get that? **`add` method never invokes `toString()`.**

> I just wanted to know how this two lines are working:
>
> list.add(this);
>
> System.out.println(list);

list.add(this) will add current object to list.

and, while printing an object, the `toString()` method is invoked. If the class doesn't have toString method defined, each object will get it from `Object` super most class.

Answer (score 0):

You are right that `this` refers to the current object and here in this case it means -

`SharedState sharedState = new SharedState();`
and `list.add(this)` means sharedState object i.e. the object on which this constructor has been called.

Answer (score 0):

this refers to current object so each object which call SharedState() is added to the list . You can check that on creation of object like below

```
SharedState obj=new SharedState();
```

**obj** object is added to **list**

```
System.out.println(list);
```

above line is similar to calling list.toString() and printing it on console